# Notepad++ Regular Expression replace first digit

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text in Notepad++ (mobile numbers). For example:

```
<phoneMobile>81234567890</phoneMobile>
```

or

```
<phoneMobile>+71234567890</phoneMobile>
```

I search with this regex:

```
<phoneMobile>(8|\+7)9[0-9]{2}[0-9]{7}</phoneMobile>
```

and I'd like to replace first digit or '+7'. Result after replace must be 1234567890. How can I do it?

Comment: don't get it. replace what to what?

Comment: so you want to delete the optional plus and the first digit?

Comment: Have you thought about making it simple and just doing two find/replaces instead of trying to combine it into one?

Comment: @genisage, yes I want delete optioal first plus and first digit

Comment: @mason, you're right I need doing two simple find/replaces

Comment: You don't need two steps; use the expression from my answer below and you'll replace everything in only one step.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

`s/\+?[78](9\d{9})/\1/`

Answer (score 0):

Content:

```
<phoneMobile>81234567890</phoneMobile>
<phoneMobile>+71234567890</phoneMobile>
```

Find what:

```
(?:>8|\+7)
```

Replace with:

```
''
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sW6oY3/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work
**Find What:** `(>(\+[\d]))|(>([\d]))` 
**Replace With:** `>`
**Explanation:**

```
(>(\+[\d]))  : Find a pattern with ">" , + and a digit 
|            : OR
(>([\d]))    : Find a pattern with ">" and a digit
```

Tried this solution in notepad++ 6.6.8